# Vim autocmd FileType not being evaluated on startup

Tags: windows, vim

I have written

```
autocmd! FileType tex set nonumber
```

in my `_vimrc` (running Windows), but when I open up my `test.tex` I still see line numbers.
If, after opening the file, I type `set filetype=tex` then the line numbers disappear.

How can I get it to evaluate when I open the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
autocmd! FileType plaintex set nonumber
```

Comment: That would have never occurred to me.

Comment: Care to explain why plaintex works and tex does not? I have a similar problem with c files.